# ¿Dónde se pone la tilde cuando se alarga artificialmente una vocal?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación

En español escrito, sobre todo en contextos informales (cómics, chats... aunque también en titulares de periódicos) no es raro encontrarse a veces con una palabra en la que alguna de las vocales se ha repetido artificialmente para expresar una pronunciación más alargada, a modo de grito. Ejemplos:

[image: ¡Gooool!]
[image: ¡Mamaaá!]
[image: ¡Nooooooooooooo!]

En el segundo ejemplo, la palabra original es "mamá", con tilde en la última A, que es precisamente la vocal alargada.
En ese caso el autor ha puesto la tilde solamente **en la última vocal** (*¡Mamaaá!*), pero también he visto casos de poner la tilde sólo **en la primera** (*¡Mamáaa!*) o **en todas** (*¡Mamááá!*).

Quizá, por no ser "mamaaá" una palabra real, no exista una norma al respecto, pero por si acaso... **¿Existe alguna norma o referencia sobre cómo tildar palabras en las que, como recurso expresivo, se alarga una vocal que casualmente lleva tilde?**

Comment: Es muy curioso. Este fin de semana hablaba con mi familia sobre esto mismo y hoy pensaba hacer la pregunta :O

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La [RAE escribe en Twitter](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/439361158899052544?lang=es) que se acentúan todas las vocales repetidas si la palabra original lleva tilde en esa vocal:

> [#RAEconsultas](https://twitter.com/hashtag/RAEconsultas?src=hash&lang=es) Cuando se alarga expresivamente la vocal con tilde en una palabra, deben tildarse todas las vocales repetidas: ¡Mamáááá!

En la *Ortografía de la lengua española (2010)* encontramos la [norma](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QuOIxwoUTHVrzLCI) que lo confirma, transcribo el fragmento en cuestión:

> «No obstante, cuando, por razones expresivas, se escriba
>   consecutivamente una misma vocal varias veces para reflejar en la
>   escritura el sostenimiento en el habla del sonido que esta representa,
>   se repitirá asimismo la tilde en cada letra si la vocal debe llevarla
>   en la palabra correspondiente: *"Repetía cada vez más fuerte: —Quiero
>   irme de aquí, quiero irme de aquí, quiero irme de aquí. ¡Quiero
>   irmeeee de aquííííííí!"* (Cohen Muerte [Esp.1993])».